# Simple algorithm provably correct using single-variable calculus

Tags: calculus, optimization, algorithms

Let $S$ be a student who wants to see calculus applied to algorithms. Student $S$ knows the following topics from single-variable calculus.

- Derivatives
- Basic optimization
- Taylor series

What example should one show $S$? I would prefer an algorithm with at least one of the following properties:

- Its correctness can be proved using the above topics
- Some parameter in the algorithm is optimized using basic optimization

I know of many such algorithms, but they tend to involve either (1) too much additional background or (2) pages of algebra and notational gymnastics, with the calculus part merely the last step.

So I guess I'm looking for an algorithm which is relatively interesting, proved using calculus, but not so circuitous that you need to squint to see the calculus.

Comment: Root finding by bisection (linear convergence) really only uses continuity (qua Intermediate Value Theorem), while Newton's method and its eventually quadratic convergence is a pretty concise application of Taylor series with remainder.  Various methods "in between" (superlinear convergence like false position) have more proof "gymnastics".

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned in a comment, you can prove the quadratic convergence of Newton's method (under the usual assumption that $f'(x^{*})\neq 0$) using Taylor series.  You can also show that when the first derivative is 0 at the root, then Newton's method gives only linear convergence.

Another interesting thing to do at this level is look at formulas for finite difference approximations to derivatives.  If you know the accuracy of your function evaluations, you can work out an optimal step size to use in a forward difference or centered difference scheme.  It's particularly instructive to see that in finite precision the finite difference approximations actually break down when $h$ is too small.